# How to display af pdf image in the markdown on github

Tags: html, github, markdown

I have been looking on other questions and answers especially this one:
[Display pdf image in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777166/display-pdf-image-in-markdown)
But i still do not get it.

I have a link to a pdf from dropbox (i have also tried google drive) Links (same picture): https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1hdh6vlcoknwsb/software_achitecture.pdf

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SFAAmHxWcK9QbVybjVY4_jMYTsLnWHn1

Code

```
<object data="https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1hdh6vlcoknwsb/software_achitecture.pdf?dl=0" type="application/pdf" width="700px" height="700px">
    <embed src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1hdh6vlcoknwsb/software_achitecture.pdf?dl=0">
        <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1hdh6vlcoknwsb/software_achitecture.pdf?dl=0">Download PDF</a>.</p>
    </embed>
</object>
```

what do i do wrong?

Comment: that's actually not a link to the pdf file, even thought the URL ends in .pdf. Use the following instead: https://ucbda2a84f41e73e72cc9515edb0.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/AXyT-8y9ZVkm2oLcjQe27I0t4_b-OkHi6htxdsbc7JjUHl7rFK0b4AcG6IDFeTTATTAnX1jTNLhsjjg_wsj1C57SKiXDVj3tLrjfXaHOTSEHXkiADx9rTfCtC0aOeB9cw_i5MoLYuGwy0aB70JKtDLJmatgEuHgtsSSSWxRPYEosG3_-f7coNP-j2oa4AAKfexg/file?_download_id=738173871806555410423380485589641225770996420031423292847615574475&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1